# react router / i wanna go to a new page instead of adding the component under the mother component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

when i click on order button i wanna go to a new page instead o staying on Buying form component and adding orderComplited component down of it

[BuyForm.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTbs1.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTJoP.png)

[orderCompleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hqr3.png)

Comment: Instead of images of your code, please update your question to include *actual* formatted and readable code snippets. Images are not searchable, not copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read. Remember, this post is not only for you, but for all future readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are rendering your `OrderCompleted` route as a nested route with the `Outlet` being rendered by the `BuyForm` route.

[image]

```
<Route path="order" element={<BuyForm />}>
  <Route path="orderCompleted" element={<OrderCompleted />} />
</Route>
```

The `BuyForm` component is a layout component. This means the `BuyForm` component remains on the screen rendered while subroutes are also matched and rendered.

To resolve you should refactor the code a bit. Move the `BuyForm` component into its own route which will be designated as the index route to be matched and rendered when the layout `Route` components path matches. Remove the `Outlet` from `BuyForm, one will be rendered by default now by the wrapping` Route`. Now both the` BuyForm`and`OrderCompleted`routes will be rendered into the`Outlet`, one at-a-time, when their` path`s match.

```
<Route path="order">
  <Route index element={<BuyForm />} />
  <Route path="orderCompleted" element={<OrderCompleted />} />
</Route>
```